# Update database values for checkboxes using PHP PDO not updating all checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

I have 3 rows and each row has a checkbox, when I uncheck all boxes and click save I receive the error in my else statement. If I uncheck on box at a time and click save, when I get to the last checkbox and click save I also receive the error in the else statement.

Here is my question - How do I allow all checkboxes to be unchecked without receiving an error?

Here is my PHP code:

```
//Update Social Preferences with new value for display on homepage
$settingsArray = array('myfacebook', 'mytwitter', 'mygoogle');
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{          
      if(isset( $_POST['mysocial']))
      {
          $values = array();
      foreach($_POST['mysocial'] as $selection )
      {  if(in_array($selection, $settingsArray))
         {  $values[ $selection ] = 1; }
         else
         {  $values[ $selection ] = 0; }
      } // end of foreach.

      $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

      try // save user selection to the database
      {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE social_preferences SET my_facebook = :myfacebook, my_twitter = :mytwitter, my_google = :mygoogle WHERE user_id = :userID");
        $stmt->bindParam(":userID", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':myfacebook', $values['myfacebook']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mytwitter', $values['mytwitter']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mygoogle', $values['mygoogle']);
        $stmt->execute();

        header("Location: admin-social-test.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to admin-social-test.php"); 
       }  catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
  }
  else
  {  $noCheckbox = 'No checkbox selection made...'; }     
} // End of, if statement from the button check
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="myfacebook" <?php echo ($result['my_facebook']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mytwitter" <?php echo ($result['my_twitter']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mygoogle" <?php echo ($result['my_google']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Checkboxes not checked don't get sent in the POST. In other words you never see an unchecked checkbox in the POST array unless you do something specifically to fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come checkbox state is not always passed along to PHP script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520952/how-come-checkbox-state-is-not-always-passed-along-to-php-script)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure I understand. When I uncheck 1 box it will send it to POST and update the database. It's only when I get to the last checkbox or try to uncheck all at once, it does not work.

Comment: The linked question does not work for me. I would have to re-write code for what looks like a work around to me. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I stand correct I made a few changes based on the answer to the linked question and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a hidden input for each one.

So I changes this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="myfacebook" <?php echo ($result['my_facebook']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mytwitter" <?php echo ($result['my_twitter']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mygoogle" <?php echo ($result['my_google']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
```

To this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mysocial[]" value="myfacebook1" <?php echo ($result['my_facebook']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="myfacebook" <?php echo ($result['my_facebook']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="hidden" name="mysocial[]" value="mytwitter1" <?php echo ($result['my_twitter']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mytwitter" <?php echo ($result['my_twitter']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="hidden" name="mysocial[]" value="mygoogle1" <?php echo ($result['my_google']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="mysocial[]" value="mygoogle" <?php echo ($result['my_google']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> />
```

This seems to have got it working.