# Echo in an image

Tags: php, database, image, echo

In my code i need to echo $row["description"]; in an image to display value in to display value in the database. The value in the database need to be display in the image. How should I write whole the code that It could echo the value? Any help??

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <img src="grey.jpg">
    <div class="top-left"> echo $row["description"]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should put php code in php tag, like `<?php echo $row["description"]  ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Because of the question written I dont know how you connected to the DB, I am assuming you are beginner. First things:

- Have you even connected to the DB? What DB are you using? I am assuming you are using mysql https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Also for security reasons do research on mysql injections.
- Test connection, nothing is going to appear if your connection is dead
  [PDO Connection Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263443/pdo-connection-test)
- Is your sql query working? (run it using phpmyadmin or any database admin tool)
- Get query results 
  [Get values from database using PHP PDO and update input to checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507747/get-values-from-database-using-php-pdo-and-update-input-to-checked) and [PHP PDO with foreach and fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385965/php-pdo-with-foreach-and-fetch)
- Once all the above are working then do this

  ```
  div class="top-left"> <?php echo $row["description"]; ?> </div>
  ```

If errors continue

- var_dump row to see how your data is returned `var_dump($row)` (maybe the array is multiples dimensions that you are not seeing)
- Make sure you are echoing `<?php echo $row["description"]; ?>` in a php extension file, if it is html it will not work
- If php code and html are two different file.Are you even including the php file in your html? using `require or rquire_once`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
  <div class="top-left"> <?php echo $row["description"]; ?> </div>
```

OR

```
<div class="top-left"> <?= echo $row["description"]; ?> </div>
```

Comment: No its not working it does not show anything at all . I don't know why.. Any help ?

Comment: @Pravesh : Please show your whole page including php